# shopify extension serve giving error X No available ports found to run extension

Tags: reactjs, shopify-app

I am trying to follow the post-purchase extension by following this docs https://shopify.dev/apps/checkout/post-purchase/getting-started-post-purchase-extension

I have followed all the steps and they are working except the

```
shopify extension serve
```

it is giving me the same error continuously.

```
X No available ports found to run extension.
```

by the way I able to run the app itself with ngrok in shopify admin by `shopify node serve`.
but when i try with the extension it again giving me the error. any suggestion !!!

Comment: Hi, I was in the same boat as you but found this pull request that helped to display a better error message [https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/pull/1372/files][1] .  I am on Windows 10 so path to file, for me was C:\Ruby30-x64\lib\ruby\gems\3.0.0\gems\shopify-cli-2.5.0\lib\project_types\extension\tasks. After change got  "*A tunnel running on another port has been detected. Close the tunnel and try again.*". That helped as I was running `shopify node serve`. After closing that `shopify extension serve` worked.


  [1]: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/pull/1372/files

Answer (score 3):

PH_Laza's answer worked for me.

**Step 1:**
Go to:
`C:\Ruby30-x64\lib\ruby\gems\3.0.0\gems\shopify-cli-x.x.x\lib\project_types\extension\tasks`

**Step 2:**
Find the file `choose_next_available_port`.

**Step 3:**
Open it in a text editor

**Step 4:**
Find the line `rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED` for me it was on line `31`.

**Step 5:**
Change that line to `rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED, Errno::ETIMEDOUT`

**Step 6:**
Save and run `shopify extension serve`

References:

- https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/pull/1372/files

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).